# In bash, how do I rename files that I transfered using rsync?

Tags: bash, shell

I am currently using:

```
rsync -e ssh "$f" $destination:$destinationFolder/"$baseFileName.lck"
```

This doesn't work if baseFileName has a space in it.

I am also using baseFileName at several other places, like:

```
destChecksum="$(echo "$(ssh $destination md5sum $destinationFolder/"$baseFileName.lck")"| cut -d \  -f 1)"
```

This line also breaks in presence of a space in baseFileName.
Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
rsync -e ssh "$f" $destination:$destinationFolder/"${baseFileName// /\ }.lck"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the space in the baseFileName with a backslash character `\`.

So if the file name is `my file.txt`, you need to put its value in `$baseFileName` as `my\ file.txt`.

If you're getting the baseFileName from a file, you could use a tool like `sed` to search and replace space characters with a backslash and space character.